# Where can I find authoritative info on the progress of individual C++ proposals?

Tags: c++, standards

Is there a single authoritative source on the progress of proposals formally submitted to the C++ standards committee? If so, where is it?

For example, I just went looking for progress on the proposal to allow overloading the dot operator. From Google, I eventually ended up on [Stroustrup's homepage](http://www.stroustrup.com/WG21.html) and from there I can see that the proposal has been revised as recently as this year (2016). Fortunately in this case, Stroustrup himself has an up-to-date site listing recent activity on his proposals in chronological order. In other cases I might not be so lucky.

For those of us who don't go to C++ standards committee meetings but occasionally want to check in on a proposal we're interested in, is there an authoritative or preferred site we should be using to check on the most recent revisions and committee activity for a proposal?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/std/status

Comment: In particular, search for the "mailings". Papers that can potentially reach the committee must be part of a mailing. But not every paper that's in a mailing is actually looked at.